# Perl hash of array how to check if the object exists before adding

Tags: perl, hash

I have this code to take rows and place them into `%data`. One row in DATA (last row) is a duplicate so I don’t want it to be added to `%data`. How do I check of the `app_id` and `ci_name` combination doesn’t already exist before pushing the row into `%data`? Something like

```
push .. unless {app_id already exists}
```

The code to modify:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %data;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    next if /app_id/;
    my ($app_id,$ci_name,$app_name) = split /,/;
    push @{$data{$ci_name}}, {app_id => $app_id, app_name => $app_name };
}

print Dumper(\%data);

__DATA__
app_id,ci_name,app_name
1234,hosta7,Managed File Transfer
1235,hosta7,Patrtol
1236,hosta7,RELATIONAL DATA WAREHOUSE
1237,hosta7,Managed File Transfer
1238,hosta7,Initio Application
1239,hosta7,Data Warehouse Operations Infrastructure
2345,hostb,Tableou
2345,hostb,Tableou
```

Answer (score 3):

You could temporarily use a HoH instead of a HoA.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

<DATA>;  # Skip header.

my %data;
my %seen;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($app_id, $ci_name, $app_name) = split /,/;
    $data{$ci_name}{$app_id} //= { app_id => $app_id, app_name => $app_name };
}

# Convert HoH to HoA.
$data{$_} = [ values(%{ $data{$_} }) ]
   for keys(%data);

print Dumper(\%data);
```

The above keeps the first of the duplicates, and it doesn't preserve order. Change `//=` to `=` to keep the last of the duplicates. Read on for a solution that preserves order.

---

The following is a common way of removing duplicates while preserving order:

```
my %seen;
my @uniq = grep !$seen{$_}++, @values;
```

We can adapt that idiom to our needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

<DATA>;  # Skip header.

my %data;
my %seen;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($app_id, $ci_name, $app_name) = split /,/;
    push @{ $data{$ci_name} }, { app_id => $app_id, app_name => $app_name }
       if !$seen{$ci_name}{$app_id}++;
}

print Dumper(\%data);
```

The above keeps the first of the duplicates, and it preserves order.

---

Both of these solution have a speed of O(N), whereas the previously posted solution has a speed of O(N<sup>2</sup>), so this solution scales much better. To be honest though, the previously posted solution has a practical speed of O(N) unless there's a lot of duplicates.

---

Note how I added `<DATA>` before the loop? It's far better than skipping all lines that contain `app_id` anywhere in the line!

Comment: I can't use ```next if $seen{$app_id}++;``` since the same app_id may be a valid row for multiple hosts but not for the same host. So for example 2345,hostb,Tableou and 2345,hosta,Tableou

Comment: That's not what your question said, so I fixed it. You can use `$seen{$ci_name}{$app_id}++`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [grep()](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) with a block, that checks if the `app_id` equals the one to be inserted.

```
...
push @{$data{$ci_name}}, {app_id => $app_id, app_name => $app_name } unless grep { $_->{'app_id'} == $app_id; } @{$data{$ci_name}};
...
```

Comment: and then [List::MoreUtils::any](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#any-BLOCK-LIST) is more efficient (exits on first find), what may add up here since it checks every single time.  Also, you'd need to check whether `$ci_name` key `exists` in the first place

Comment: (if the key doesn't exist and we still try to use it then _it is created_ ... so then _it does exist_, even though no such data has been seen and there's nothing there.  That may --  or may not -- be a problem later)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all records (adapted from @ikegami):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

<DATA>;  # Skip header.

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($app_id, $ci_name, $app_name) = split /,/;
    push @{ $data{$ci_name}{$app_id} }, { app_id => $app_id, app_name => $app_name };
}

print Dumper(\%data);
```

But then it would be better to code:

```
$data{$ci_name}{$app_id}{$app_name}++;
```

Comment: This still keeps the duplicate, no?  (It adds the same hashref twice to `@{$data{hostb}{2345}}` array ?)  They specifically don't want them